# D3 using Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, d3.js

I'm building an Ember.js's application. I would like to vizualize a Multiple line chart with dataset selection bound to a `"select"` element.
The link is [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955#data.tsv).
In my `"index"` template I added my select and a `"visu-chart"` component.
I want to visualize my chart in the component but it doesn't work.

How can I do?
Here is my code [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/sidotejuzi/edit?html,css,js,output)

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  controllerName: 'application'
});

App.VisuChartComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  didRenderElement: function() {
      var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
     width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
     height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

  var x = d3.time.scale()
      .range([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

  var color = d3.scale.category10();

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

  var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("basis")
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.xValue); })
      .y(function(d) { return y(d.yValue); });

  var svg = d3.select(".visu-chart").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "xValue"; }));

    var data = this.get("agro");

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.xValue = parseDate(d.xValue);
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.xValue; }));

    y.domain([
      d3.min(cities, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.yValue; }); }),
      d3.max(cities, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.yValue; }); })
    ]);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("yValue (ºF)");

        //Mise en place des lignes
 
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
        .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

    svg.append("text")
        .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.xValue) + "," + y(d.value.yValue) + ")"; })
        .attr("x", 3)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
    },

 // Used only for scatter chart
  agro: 
  {
"Biomass/100 (g DM/m2)": [
{
"xValue": 1,
"yValue": 0
},
{
"xValue": 2,
"yValue": 10
},
{
"xValue": 3,
"yValue": 20
},
{
"xValue": 4,
"yValue": 25
},
{
"xValue": 5,
"yValue": 39
}
],
"C/N_{bio}": [
{
"xValue": 1,
"yValue": 14.0833
},
{
"xValue": 2,
"yValue": 34.0833
},
{
"xValue": 3,
"yValue": 44.0833
},
{
"xValue": 4,
"yValue": 50.0833
},
{
"xValue": 5,
"yValue": 54.0833
}
]
}   
});
```

```css
body {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .x.axis path {
      display: none;
    }

    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="description" content="Ember-Charts Starter Kit" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ember Charts Starter Kit</title>
      
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/2.1.0/normalize.css">
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      
      <!-- Ember and dependencies -->
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.3.0/handlebars.js"></script>
      <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.4.0/ember.js"></script>
      
      <!-- Ember Charts and dependencies -->
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.10/d3.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <script type="text/x-handlebars">
        <h2> Welcome to Ember Charts!</h2>
        <p>Version 0.3.0</p>
        {{outlet}}
      </script>

      <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
     <div class="col-md-3">
      <h3>Choisir le Groupe</h3>
      <div class="selectPicker">
        <select id="graphselection" name="dataset" action="change-dataset">
          <option value="all">All</option>
          {{#each dataset in model}}
            <option value="{{dataset}}">{{dataset}}</option>
          {{/each}}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9">
      {{visu-chart dataset=agro elementId="scatter-load"}}
    </div>
      </script>
      <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/visu-chart">
        <div class="visu-chart"></div>
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please paste your codes in the question ( **edit** your question )

Comment: This is incorrect d3("data", function(error, data) {...it can be d3.tsv d3.csv d3.json...depending on the type of data that you are trying to pull via ajax

Comment: The type of data is Json